# Unable to convert classes into dex format

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, google-cardboard

I'm creating an app for VR using cardboard and imported CardboardSDKForUnity, when i tried to Build&Run it on the unity it works fine, but when i tried to run it on my device(samsung s7 edge) it shows an error unable to convert classes into dex format.

```
-CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format.
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -
Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/astudio-sdk\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 
-jar "C:\Program Files\Unity 
2017.2.0b11\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to Java and download last JDK.
[Link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)
And update your SDK tools.